# Why is Dropbox erring on startup?

Tags: dropbox

I opened up Dropbox and received this error:

[image: Dropbox Error]

I am on an Intel i5 MBP running 10.6.8. Dropbox is version 1.1.45.

Console log:

```
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434] 'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434] Traceback (most recent call last):
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434]   File "Resources/__boot__.py", line 103, in <module>
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434]   File "Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in _argv_emulation
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434]   File "Resources/__boot__.py", line 7, in _get_argvemulator
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  [0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434] zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  Dropbox[2434]   Dropbox Error
11/1/11 9:54:56 AM  Dropbox[2434]   Dropbox Error An unexpected error has occurred during execution of the main script
ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
11/1/11 9:54:58 AM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.504[607]  ([0x0-0x156156].com.getdropbox.dropbox[2434]) Exited with exit code: 255
```

Comment: Did you "Open Console"?

Comment: I concur with @patrix: the Console output would be more than helpful to diagnose this.

Comment: Also, have you tried manually updating to the latest stable build?

Comment: Have you exhausted the dropbox support website? They will know the best how to react to errors in their program. List a little more in your question - what you tried / what versions of DropBox and your OS for sure. Perhaps if you are on Intel/PPC might be relevant.

Comment: @patrix Thanks for adding the log file. I couldn't figure out how to format it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google showed](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=zipImportError%3a%20can%27t%20decompress%20data;%20zlib%20not%20available&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=zipImportError%3a%20can%27t%20decompress%20data;%20zlib%20not%20available%20mac%20dropbox&pbx=1&oq=zipImportError%3a%20can%27t%20decompress%20data;%20zlib%20not%20available%20mac%20dropbox&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=13444l14895l1l15200l8l8l0l0l0l0l243l1522l0.4.4l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2be8271d96c3df42&biw=1242&bih=913) that it is the case with 10.3 while Dropbox only support 10.4 and upwards.

Judging by the screenshot it is not your case so there is either a problem with [zlib](http://zlib.net/) on your system or with permissions. Then either Disk Utility or [booting from install disk and repair user permissions](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20013630-263.html) might help.

If nothing above try to remove Dropbox with a cleaner app and install anew.

Comment: I re-installed Dropbox. Don't know what happened, but thanks for your quick answer!